# expected '{' symbol error in java programming

Tags: java

I try to figure out which line I miss the "{". it tells me in the 3rd line I expected to put "{" symbol and I did but still gives me an error.
this is my code:

```
package lab22;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        int coffee = 0;
        int tea = 0;
        int coke = 0;
        int orange = 0;
        int pnum = 1;

        System.out.println("Baverage:\n1. Coffee\n2. Tea\n3. Coke\n4. Orange Juice");
        do{
            System.out.println("Please input the favourite beverage of person #"+ String.valueOf(pnum)+": Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4 from the above menu or -1 to exit");
            choice = Sc.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1){
                coffee += 1;
            } else if (choice == 2){
                tea += 1;
            } else if (choice == 3){
                coke += 1;
            } else if (choice == 4){
                orange += 1;
            } else if (choice != -1){
                System.out.println("Please enter valid input!");
                continue;
            }
            pnum += 1;
        } while(choice != -1);
        System.out.println("          Beverage Number of Votes");
        System.out.println("          *************************");
        System.out.println("Coffee:          "+ String.valueOf(coffee));
        System.out.println("Tea:             "+ String.valueOf(tea));
        System.out.println("Coke:            "+ String.valueOf(coke));
        System.out.println("Orange Jiuce:    "+ String.valueOf(coffee));
    
    
    
    }
}
```

[image]

can someone help what did i miss?

Comment: `public class main.java` this is not a correct syntax

Comment: remove the .java. Also, start following naming syntax, it 'll help you keeping your code readable in the long run

Comment: @ZidaneLeong Your edits have invalidated your question, as since your edit, your class name is no longer `main.java`.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting your code you need to first understand basic naming conventions in Java.

As far as error concern you need to remove that `.java` from class name to get rid of the error.

Additionally:

a) Class name should start with Capital Letter (CamelCase).

b) Variable name should start with Small Letter (CamelCase).

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0;
    int coffee = 0;
    int tea = 0;
    int coke = 0;
    int orange = 0;
    int pnum = 1;

    System.out.println("Baverage:\n1. Coffee\n2. Tea\n3. Coke\n4. Orange Juice");
    do {
      System.out.println("Please input the favourite beverage of person #" + String.valueOf(pnum)
          + ": Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4 from the above menu or -1 to exit");
      choice = sc.nextInt();
      if (choice == 1) {
        coffee += 1;
      } else if (choice == 2) {
        tea += 1;
      } else if (choice == 3) {
        coke += 1;
      } else if (choice == 4) {
        orange += 1;
      } else if (choice != -1) {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid input!");
        continue;
      }
      pnum += 1;
    } while (choice != -1);
    System.out.println("          Beverage Number of Votes");
    System.out.println("          *************************");
    System.out.println("Coffee:          " + String.valueOf(coffee));
    System.out.println("Tea:             " + String.valueOf(tea));
    System.out.println("Coke:            " + String.valueOf(coke));
    System.out.println("Orange Jiuce:    " + String.valueOf(coffee));

  }
}
```

As I have changed the class name, probably you would need to rename your file also containing the class as `Main.java`.

Comment: i edit it already but it still show this error

Comment: What error? In your screenshot error is in some other file now. File name is ending with *lab2.java